# Why is FLAGS necessary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I cannot understand why FLAGS is necessary in TensorFlow.
Now I study TensorFlow in my book.

```
# coding: utf-8

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image

from reader import Cifar10Reader

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('file',None,"path")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('offset',0,"record")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('length',16,"change record")

basename = os.path.basename(FLAGS.file)
path = os.path.dirname(FLAGS.file)

reader = Cifar10Reader(FLAGS.file)

stop = FLAGS.offset + FLAGS.length

for index in range(FLAGS.offset,stop):
    image = reader.read(index)

    print('label: %d' % image.label)
    imageshow = Image.fromarray(image.byte_array.astype(np.unit8))

    file_name = '%s-%02d-%d.png' % (basename,index,image.label)
    file = os.path.join(path,file_name)
    with open(file,mode='wb') as out:
        imageshow.save(out,format='png')

reader.close()
```

I wrote like these codes, and I cannot understand

```
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
```

this part.
I read FLAGS was error message label, but when does it need?(Maybe my read info is wrong) 
Why  is this part necessary?
What function does this part have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `FLAGS` are used to pass command line arguments into your program. E.g.

```
import tensorflow as tf
fs = tf.app.flags
fs.DEFINE_integer('n_epochs', 25, 'number of epochs to train [25]')
FLAGS = fs.FLAGS

def main(argv):
    print(FLAGS.n_epochs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

If you run this snippet from the command line as `python snippet.py`, it will print

```
25
```

If you run `python snippet.py --n_epochs 50` it will print

```
50
```

You could achieve the same thing with python's package `argparse`.

In the example you posted the use of `FLAGS` is admittedly a bit strange. Here it could be replaced by just directly defining the variables, unless the `FLAGS` variable is used someplace else in the code, which you are not showing here.